# How to determine if the user signed in to Firebase with email and password or with google sign in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am working on a log in for a web application, and I have made it so the user can sign in manually with their email and password or by using a google sign in. Is there a way to determine which method they used? Preferably by using the Firebase authentication state change function.

```
`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {....`
```

I know you can tell how they signed in when you go into the Firebase console log but is there a way to determine it using JavaScript code?

When using `firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData` the following:
[image]

Comment: Did you check UserInfo? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.UserInfo

"providerId
string
The authentication provider ID for the current user. For example, 'facebook.com', or 'google.com'."

Comment: Do you mean like firebase.auth().currentUser.providerId? because when I printed it out to the console log to test it, it just prints out firebase.

Comment: Hmm.. What is firebase.auth().currentUser returning? I assume an object.

Comment: It returns an [object Object]

Comment: Could you provide more code snippets? For example in plunker.

Comment: I have just tried use in firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0] and it provides a list of everything ie displayname, email, uid, providerId. Do you know how I get the providerId from that?

Comment: How about firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].providerId ?

Comment: Haha I tried it with firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData.providerId and it didn't work. I didn't think of trying it with firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].providerId. Thanks it works now.

Comment: Awesome! Have fun coding :)

Comment: Please vote up my answer and check as solved, so other people can see the solution immediately :) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine by using currentUser https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.UserInfo

Like this:

`firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].providerId`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

@mjrdnk's answer is correct, but there is a caveat, a user could have multiple providers linked. So using `firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].providerId` will always yield the same provider even when another linked provider was used to sign in. The most accurate way to determine the current provider used to sign is by inspecting the ID token's field: `firebase.sign_in_provider`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "The most accurate way to determine the current provider used to sign is by inspecting the ID token's field: `firebase.sign_in_provider`."

Comment: When you sign in a user, a Firebase ID token is returned. You can get that ID token via `currentUser.getIdToken()`. The token contains information like its issuer, audience, user email, phone number, authentication time, refresh time, expiration, etc, and of importance to you, the method of sign in. You just need to base64 decode the token's payload to get that information. To understand this, manually copy a user's ID token and paste it into https://jwt.io to inspect its payload. This method is the best way to get sign in provider as a user could have multiple providers linked to it.

Comment: Rather than call `currentUser.getIdToken()`, you can call `currentUser.getIdTokenResult()` instead to get the decoded data.

Answer (score 3):

Currently @mjdnk asnwer depracated, because it will gives always first provider not the last logged in.

So most recent solution is:

As noted [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/README.md#example-with-all-parameters-used)

```
var uiConfig = {
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            var providerId = authResult.additionalUserInfo.providerId;
            localStorage.setItem("firebaseProviderId", providerId)
            //...
          },
          //..
       }
```

and for display in page

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {

          $('#user').text(welcomeName + "(" + localStorage.getItem("firebaseProviderId")+ ")");
          $('#logged-in').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Capturing the provider info at sign in for the specific browser is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

@mjrdnk's answer is correct, but there are cases that are not covered by the answer so I find that this solution works best in all cases (that I have tested).

```
val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser

        user?.let {

        authProvider = when (it.providerData[it.providerData.size-1].providerId) {
            "phone" -> {
                ConnectedUser.LOGIN_PROVIDERS.PHONE
            }
            "password" -> {
                // Email and password
                ConnectedUser.LOGIN_PROVIDERS.EMAIL
            }
            else -> {
                ConnectedUser.LOGIN_PROVIDERS.UNKNOWN
            }
        }
.
.
.
```

Wonderful source of information:  [FirebaseUI for Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth)

Some provider names follow (see above source code for more):

```
ANONYMOUS_PROVIDER = "anonymous"
EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD = "emailLink"
EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD = "password"
MICROSOFT_PROVIDER = "microsoft.com"
YAHOO_PROVIDER = "yahoo.com"
APPLE_PROVIDER = "apple.com"
PHONE = "phone"
```