# Check if user is logged in: Firebase iOS Swift 4

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, swift4, appdelegate

I am still having difficulty in checking whether the user is logged in with Google or Facebook to read and write on Firebase Database. I want to present a log in screen to a first time user and when the user authenticates, the log in screen is dismissed and it sent to the tabViewControllers. Here's my Swift 4 code below, which is placed in the AppDelegate, application(application:didFInishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:).

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
    print("NO USER") // this does print out in the console before the app crashes
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") as! LogInViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
    } else {
        let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        if let tabViewControllers = tabController.viewControllers {  
            // First tab (only one so far...)
            let navController = tabViewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
            let controller1 = navController.viewControllers.first as! UserProfileViewController
            controller1.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the LogInViewController Scene is created in the Main.storyboard file and it has a Storyboard ID of "loginVC". When I try to run this, the program crashes at the part where the tabViewController[0] tries to fetch from the coreDataStack.

Comment: Check this post to determine what provider was used to sign in with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225100/how-to-determine-if-the-user-signed-in-to-firebase-with-email-and-password-or-wi

Comment: I am trying another implementation and edited my post, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to store UID of the user here is my code for login screen as you said if user open app for first time he have to login / authenticate and second time is automatically.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let uid = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: KEY_UID) {
            autoLoginWithUID(uid: uid)
        }
    }
```

after app launches try it to auto login him if have stored his UID otherwise screen stays

```
 func autoLoginWithUID(uid: String) {
     KeychainWrapper.standard.set(uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
     print(uid)
    //Keep db and userRef as class constants shouldn't be here
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userRef = db.collection("Users").document(uid)

     userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
          print("User data: \(document.data())")
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogIn", sender: nil)
        } else {
        print("User does not exist")
        }
     }     
}
```

Here I look in db if I have user with this UID if I got it its stored in global variable and continue. You can also store users credentials and log user by them. But dont know which way is more secure.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
  if let error = error {
    // ...
    return
  }
  // User is signed in
  // ...
 }
}
```

If you want more code from UserRequest let me know ;)

Comment: Hi Robin. Thanks for the input. Is the first block of code placed in the viewDidLoad() of the screen I want to first present? Looks like I have to include the SwiftKeychainWrapper pod file to access the KeychainWrapper class. Yes, how would I access the UserRequest class?

Comment: This code is in viewDidLoad in LoginViewController, UserRequest is class where i have all Firebase communication which has something to do with Users. You dont have to use KeychainWrapper pod (you can use UserDefaults) but i like it and make things easy.

Comment: I edited my answer so it should help you to check if user exist and  get you user data

Comment: I checked your question and its very very bad how you want to auth user. In Did finish launching ? Thats bad man. I will edit my answer so you will find out how it should be.

Comment: Yeah, when I think about it, the call to Auth.auth().currentUser should be checked in the UserLogInViewController.